# Count Array within an Object and Replace

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I currently have an object that is returning this:

```
Object {1: 0, 2: Array[2], 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
```

What I am trying to do is 'replace' the "Array[2]" with just the number "2" (counting how many records are in the array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code

```
var obj = {1: 0, 2: [0, 1], 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        obj[key] = obj[key].length;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object.keys(your_object).forEach(function(index){
    if (toString.call(your_object[index]) === '[object Array]') {
        your_object[index] = your_object[index].length;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to convert all arrays to it's equivalent length.

```
for( var key in obj ) {

  if( obj[key] instanceof Array ) {
    obj[key] = obj[key].length;
  }

}
```